# Mathematica: adding a list of lists elementwise

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, addition, elementwise-operations

I have a list of lists of numbers. I add them into one list by adding all of the first elements together, all of the second elements together, etc. For example, if my list were { {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4} } I would want to end up with {3,6,9,4}. How do I do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};

Total@PadRight@a
```

> {3, 6, 9, 4}

Answer (score 1):

Among its many useful features, [Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) will transpose a 'ragged' array (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument/126#126) for a nice explanation, or check out the 'applications' subsection of the documentation on  [Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html))

```
Total /@ Flatten[#, {{2}}] &@{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

> {3, 6, 9, 4}

Answer (score 0):

If all the rows were the same length then adding the rows would do this.

So make all the rows the same length by appending zeros and then add them.

```
lists = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
max = Max[Length /@ lists]; min = Min[Length /@ lists];
zeros = Table[0, {max - min}];
Plus @@ Map[Take[Join[#, zeros], max] &, lists]
```